# FAL insertion into sys_file TYPO3

Tags: file, typo3

I'm trying to insert a file into TYPO3 db through frontend using core functions or FileRepository, exactly into sys_file table.
While investigating I've seen few solutions like,

```
$storageRepository = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Resource\\StorageRepository');
$storage = $storageRepository->findByUid(1);

$fileObject = $storage->addFile('/tmp/myfile', $storage->getRootLevelFolder(), 'newFile');
echo $fileObject->getIdentifier(); // Should output "/newFile"
```

But I still can't find this `addFile()` in storageRepository class. Am I missing some thing here?

Comment: Do you get an error? What is the question?

Comment: I meant.. I need to add a sys_file record with the data of file uploaded via frontend of my extension. No errors at all.. But as snippet suggests there is no addFile() in StorageRepository.

Comment: The snippet works. I used it yesterday. See answer from @mario.

Comment: snippet ??  using ResourceStorage class ??

Comment: Have you checked the link mario posted? I don't see what the problem is. I'll post a more complete code later.

Answer (score 2):

The line `$storageRepository->findByUid(1)` return a `ResourceStorage` Object with the Method `addFile()`.

Here is a Documenttion of this class.
https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_resource_1_1_resource_storage.html

Answer (score -1):

@mario Thanks. By the way I've achieved what I planned. Here's what I did..

```
public function uploadFile($uploadedfile) {

    $storage = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Resource\\StorageRepository');

    $filePath = 'uploads/tx_fileupload/'.$uploadedfile['updata']['name'];
    $title = $uploadedfile['updata']['name'];
    $size = $uploadedfile['updata']['size'];
    
    // Moving the physical file to destined folder
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::upload_copy_move($uploadedfile['updata']['tmp_name'],$filePath);

    // Adding a record in sys_file_storage
    $fileObject = $storage->createLocalStorage($uploadedfile['updata']['name'],$uploadedfile['updata']['tmp_name'],$filePath,'');

    // Inserting file in sys_file
    $repositoryFileObject = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceFactory::getInstance()->retrieveFileOrFolderObject($filePath);

    return $repositoryFileObject;
}
```

Now moving onto adding corresponding `sys_file_reference` record.

Comment: did you find a solution?